# Do you know written solutions for auto-deploy a new Django DB for every new subdomain?

Tags: django, apache, nginx, deployment

I have a product, which required a separate DB for every customer. Now I'm using one Django source code and separate settings and wsgi for every customer which is in a separate VirtualHost of Apache.

Currently everything works fine, but when we add a new customer - we need to restart apache.

I'm going to move to nginx, but maybe someone can recommend any tools that allow me to automate those steps when new customer sign up:
- new mysql DB
- settings
- wsgi
- requests to create subdomain at hosting panel (DO)
etc

Thanks

p.s. I'm not asking for criticism to that solution, as every customer is a large business, a whole architecture require current solution

Answer (score 0):

I found that article hope it'll help ;) 
[How To Migrate from an Apache Web Server to Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-an-apache-web-server-to-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps)